# From App.cs I am going to my landing page(MainPage.xaml) and then want to navigate to other page?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am navigation to MainPage.xaml from my App.cs following is my code for App.cs

```
public class App : BaseApplication
{
 public App()
 {
   MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
 }
}
```

And in my MainPage.xaml and code behind I am doing following

```
    public partial class MainPage:ContentPage
    {
     public MainPage()
     {
      InitializeComponent();
      SetPage();
     }

     async public void SetPage()
     {
        //await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Login());
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new Login());
        Navigation.RemovePage(this);
    }
}
```

This code gives me the login page but doesn't remove MainPage from stack and keeps my Android back button enable and clicking on that icon navigates me back. I really want to set Login page as a starting page in some situation. I have also tried App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Login()); but that didn't work also?

Any suggestion how do I set the Starting page dynamically from my mainpage.cs, note I don't want to do that in App.cs as I want to keep that as clean as possible?

For more details, on error, please click on [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/68329/from-app-cs-i-am-going-to-my-landing-page-mainpage-xaml-and-then-want-to-navigate-to-other-page/p1?new=1) link

Answer (score 1):

I currently have a solution with the same approach you want to do.

What I do there is something like this:

```
public async void LoginClick(object sender, EventArgs e){
        try
        {
            //Some logic code here ...
            App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new HomeView());
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            DisplayAlert("Error",exc.Message,"OK");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tested this approach with Universal window as I have tried tihis already and I keep getting the following error upon navigation to main page "at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.NavigationPageRenderer.UpdateBackButton()   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.NavigationPageRenderer.OnLoaded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)" and the error is Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: @AtulChaudhary You have to wrap the call `App.Current.MainPage = <etc...>` in a `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` method I believe.  Or at least I ran into a similar situation on UWP and got the same error you did and this is how I solved it.